# Check if there is a class and do not the code appear // prevent removing a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've something like a tabview. When I change between tabs everything works finde.

When clicking twice on a link, (so again on the `.active`) the main content of the tab gets the hidden class and is "eliminated".

How can I check or bind this behaviour so that it won't change again when clicking on the active tag and the content will still appear?

I've tried with `.hasClass()` and `if {}` like `if(!$(".tabTrigger li").hasClass("active)) {}` but this doesn't work, I think it's because of it's checking if it has the class in general or not in this particular case.

```js
$(".tabTrigger li").click(function() {
  var clickClass = $(this).attr("class");
  var selector = clickClass.replace("trigger ", "");
  $(".tabTrigger .trigger.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tabArea").addClass("hidden");
  $("#" + selector).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.trigger.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav class="tabTrigger">
    <ul>
      <li class="trigger First active">First</li>
      <li class="trigger Second">Second</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tabContent">
    <section class="tabArea" id="First">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="tabArea hidden" id="Second">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: You really should be using data attributes instead of classes for the section id you want to show and hide. Or use anchors inside the li and the href.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but by simply adding `if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){}` check inside the `click event` will work for you.

**Here is the running snippet:**

```js
$(".tabTrigger li").click(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    var clickClass = $(this).attr("class");
    var selector = clickClass.replace("trigger ", "");
    $(".tabTrigger .trigger.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tabArea").addClass("hidden");
    $("#" + selector).removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.trigger.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav class="tabTrigger">
    <ul>
      <li class="trigger First active">First</li>
      <li class="trigger Second">Second</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tabContent">
    <section class="tabArea" id="First">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="tabArea hidden" id="Second">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".tabTrigger li").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  //skip logic if the element has the active class
  if (!$this.is('.active')) {
  var clickClass = $(this).attr("class");
  var selector = clickClass.replace("trigger ", "");
  $(".tabTrigger .trigger.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tabArea").addClass("hidden");
  $("#"+selector).removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.trigger.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <nav class="tabTrigger">
  <ul>
    <li class="trigger First active">First</li>
      <li class="trigger Second">Second</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <section class="tabContent">
  <section class="tabArea" id="First">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </section>
    <section class="tabArea hidden" id="Second">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
  </section>
 </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this use attribute `tabId` which is simple and clean process.

```js
$(".tabTrigger li").click(function() {
   $(".tabTrigger .trigger.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".tabArea").addClass("hidden");
  $("#"+$(this).attr("tabId")).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.trigger.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <nav class="tabTrigger">
  <ul>
    <li class="trigger active" tabId = "First" >First</li>
      <li class="trigger" tabId = "Second" >Second</li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
 <section class="tabContent">
  <section class="tabArea" id="First">
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
  </section>
    <section class="tabArea hidden" id="Second">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
  </section>
 </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the second time you click on the link, your selector become `#First active`, hence the persistence of `hidden` class. To fix it, you can use [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to store the id of the element you want to show :

```js
$(".tabTrigger li").click(function() {
  var selector = $(this).data('triggers');
  
  $(".tabTrigger .trigger.active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  
  $(".tabArea").addClass("hidden");
  $("#" + selector).removeClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.trigger.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav class="tabTrigger">
    <ul>
      <li class="trigger active" data-triggers="First">First</li>
      <li class="trigger" data-triggers="Second">Second</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="tabContent">
    <section class="tabArea" id="First">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
    </section>
    <section class="tabArea hidden" id="Second">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```